# How to make a fieldName to fieldValue map deserializing a json string

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

I have a class having trivial string typed fields and one map only:

```
class MyClass {
  @SerializedName("handle");
  String nickName;
  Map randomDetails;
}
```

My requirement is to create a map of fieldName to fieldValue (Map) but the fieldNames should be the same as @SerializedName rather than Myclass's field name. I realize that for a complex type like MyClass I may have to do some low-level deserialization myself. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library, you shouldn't need to do *any* low-level work.

I haven't used it (yet) but [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) looks like it'll do what you need.

It would be especially easy if you're not required to use that `@SerializedName` annotation, as Jackson provides a suite of [its own annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) which do exactly what you need - (see the `@JsonProperty` annotation).

If you use the [Jackson Tree Model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) mode of operation, you should get something like the map-based results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(I think I understand that the question concerns how to use Gson to deserialize a JSON map structure to a Java `Map`.)

Gson currently needs a little bit more type information about the `Map` than the Java class structure in the original question provides.  Instead of declaring that `randomDetails` is a plain old `Map`, let Gson know that it's a `Map<String, String>`.  Then, the following example JSON and simple deserialization code runs as expected.

**input.json Contents:**

```
{
  "handle":"the handle",
  "random_details":{"one":1,"too":"B","3":false,"for":5.32}
}
```

**Foo.java:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    MyClass myObject = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), MyClass.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(myObject));
  }
}

class MyClass
{
  @SerializedName("handle")
  String nickName;
  Map<String, String> randomDetails;
}
```

Note that this converts all values in the `Map` into `Strings`.  If you wanted something more generic, like a `Map<String, Object>`, or if `randomDetails` must be a plain old `Map` without additional type information, then it's necessary to implement custom deserialization processing, [as described in the user guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).  (This is a situation where Gson unfortunately does not currently automatically generate Java values of `String` or primitive type from JSON primitives, if the declared Java type is simply `Object`.  Thus it's necessary to implement the custom deserialization.)

Here's one such example.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyClassDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    MyClass myObject = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), MyClass.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(myObject));
  }
}

class MyClassDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyClass>
{
  @Override
  public MyClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException
  {
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
    String nickName = object.get("handle").getAsString();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> mapEntries = object.get("random_details").getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
    Map randomDetails = new HashMap(mapEntries.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> mapEntry : mapEntries)
    {
      String key = mapEntry.getKey();
      Object value;
      JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = mapEntry.getValue().getAsJsonPrimitive();
      if (jsonPrimitive.isNumber()) value = jsonPrimitive.getAsNumber();
      else if (jsonPrimitive.isBoolean()) value = jsonPrimitive.getAsBoolean();
      else value = jsonPrimitive.getAsString();
      randomDetails.put(key, value);
    }
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    myObject.nickName = nickName;
    myObject.randomDetails = randomDetails;
    return myObject;
  }
}

class MyClass
{
  @SerializedName("handle")
  String nickName;
  Map randomDetails;
}
```

Comment: Gson issue 325 addresses simple deserialization to Map<String, Object>. Please don't hesitate to vote for its implementation at code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=325